# is it possible to render distant objects in lower quality?

Tags: rendering

I was wondering if there is the possibility to render distant objects in lower quality than the ones that are closer to the camera.

Answer (score 1):

Set Render Engine to Cycles and Feature Set to Experimental.

There will be a checkbox for Adaptive Subdivision in SubSurf modifier. This is what you want.
Blender Doc: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/object_settings/adaptive_subdiv.html
[image]

Comment: thanks a lot. Is there a solution for eevee?